Run 2 Flows in parallel on JMeter
I should to test a system with 2 differente flows that use different Virtual Users.
I would like to avoid writing how system works. I will make a simplified example:
I have 1 THREAD Group with the total virtual users (virtual users FLOW 1 - virtual users FLOW 2).
I should simulating the execution in parallel of both flows with the associated virtual users, because the system works in available at the same time for both the services.
For example when 1 vu arrived in the FLOW 1, I want to put 1 vu also in the FLOW 2...and each Flow will go on in parallel.
I tried to set 2 Thread Group and I unselected "Run consecutively" in the Test Plan. But I should to run the LOAD Test in NO-GUI mode and I would not like to have problems if there are 2 threads with the aggregate reports.
Is there a possibility to use only 1 thread group (with the total virtual users) and put on each flows a throughput controller with the percentage associated at the virtual users, and run the 2 flows in parallel?
Let me know,
thank you.

Yes, it is, there are multiple options on distributing the "flows" within the bounds of a single Thread Group so different virtual users would be executing different Samplers or groups of Samplers.

Throughput Controller
Switch Controller with an appropriate function or variable in the Switch value
Weighted Switch Controller
If Controller with an appropriate function or variable in the condition value

Also having 2 different Thread Groups is possible and in fact this is what you should be doing for simulating different groups of business users. If you run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode the .jtl results file will contain metrics from all virtual users from all Thread Groups, you won't need to care about anything else.
